# synchronized keyword- Does it lock two objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Say I have two hash maps hashMap1 and hashMap2, and a multithreaded concurrent Java program. If I place a synchronized block

```
synchronized(hashMap1) {
hashMap1.put(5, "Hello");
hashMap2.put(10, "Hi");
}
```

Since only one thread at once can access hashMap1, will only one thread be able to access hashMap2? I am essentially asking if hashMap2 will be protected from multiple threads accessing it at once, just like hashMap1 is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, `synchronized` doesn't "lock objects". What your block of code does is require a thread to take the lock on hashMap1 before it can enter the block. hashMap1 itself is not "locked" in any way, except that its monitor is being acquired. (Maybe it's clearer to call it a monitor than a lock.) The monitor is something that all objects have, in itself it doesn't do anything to control access to the object it belongs to. If hashMap2 is accessed elsewhere this sychronized block doesn't do anything to prevent that.

The purpose of the synchronized block is to require the thread to acquire the monitor. All places where you want that resource to be protected from concurrent access need to require taking that same lock. It's the code blocks protected with `synchronized` telling when the lock object needs to be used that control access.

The choice of monitor can be kept separate from the actual objects being protected from concurrent access. You can have a dedicated lock object and use that, there's no requirement that you have to use the lock on the things you are protecting. (The only advantage is it might help in organization, if there is only one thing you are accessing it may be convenient to use that thing's monitor.) Using a dedicated lock may be clearer:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object LOCK = new Object();

    private Map hashMap1 = new HashMap();
    private Map hashMap2 = new HashMap();

    public void doStuff() {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            ... // do stuff with hashMap1 and hashMap2
        }
    }
}
```

Keeping access to the lock private to the object means the object can limit who can acquire the lock (unlike with `synchronized(this)`). Also don't use things like Strings or Booleans that can be interned, cached, or otherwise accessed from other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon your application design. After all, synchronization is an opt-in concept - any thread could choose to ignore locks and simply access shared objects regardless.

Similarly with your example, if you are sure the only access to `hashMap2` is within the synchronized block shown in your example, then you are effectively protecting it with a lock, albeit a lock on another object.

It may be clearer for future maintainers to take locks on both objects before operating on them.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` keyword causes a thread to obtain a lock when it enters the method, only one thread can execute the method at the same time (for the given object instance, unless it is a static method).

In your situation as long as inside the `synchronized` method is the only place where hashmap2 is modified then yes it would be protected from multiple threads accessing at once. However, if hashmap2 is being modified somewhere else in addition to inside of the `synchronized` method there is no guarantee that hashmap2 will be protected.